# I can't use JQuery to get the input from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I'm trying to use Jquery to get two inputs from a form and I'm not sure why it's not working--I've tried everything I can think of

I'm still a beginner so any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
    var c = $('#canvas1');
    var ctx = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
    var container = $(c).parent();

    $(window).resize( canvas1 );
    
    function canvas1(){
        c.attr('width', $(container).width() ); //max width

        draw = function(){
       
            var options = parseInt(document.getElementById('options').value);
            var times = parseInt(document.getElementById('times').value);

            ctx.fillRect(options, times, 50, 50);
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(draw)
    }
    
    $('button').click(canvas1())
});
```

```html
<div class="option">
    <div id="error"></div>
    <form class="boxForm" id="form1">
        <input type="number" class="boxInput" id="options" name="options" max=600 min=1 required />
        <input type="number" class="boxInput" id="times" name="times" max=600 min=1 required />
        <input type="submit" class="boxSubmit" id="submit" value="GO!"/>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  You've helpfully added *a* snippet, but please read [mcve] - emphasis on *minimal required to reproduce the issue* and *complete* (you're missing `canvas` element).    As you appear to be asking about how to get a value from an input, you should reduce your code *just* to getting the value from the input - if that works for you, *then* add more code until it doesn't work and ask with that, noting what does work.

Comment: You *probably* want `$('button').click(canvas1)` (without extra brackets) - but then, you don't have a `button`...

Comment: Here's the minimum code for "get input from a form (via a click event)" - the rest (canvas code) seems to be a different issue - if it's even an issue, once you fix `$(button)` and `.click(func)` (not `.click(func())`).   https://jsfiddle.net/z3hopje5/

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry that line was a mistake--I don't actually have a button. I've removed it and it's still not working. It's not a problem with the canvas because when I give it default values it works...any idea what it could be?